# Prepend font awesome icon before input with js

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I try to prepend font-awesome icon to button called "ЗАКАЗ в 1 КЛИК" on a page [here](https://tao-online.net/shop/sku=910), but none of code works:

JS code, embedded on page

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("input#quick_buy_910_button").prepend('<i class="fa fa-cart-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
});
</script>
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: For better answer please post you relevant HTML also

Comment: sure. just a moment

Comment: `input[id="quick_buy_910_button"]:before{
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
   }
   
   input[id="quick_buy_910_button"]:before{
    content: "\f003";
   }`

Answer (score 1):

It is not permitted for content to be included in [HTML `<input>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

For the other controls in the page that you linked to, there is usage of `HTML <button> element` which permits content in it.

I suggest to update the markup to use a HTML  element instead. 
If you're able to do this, you may as well write the adornments for the button in HTML.